# RDP over SSH using Amazon EC2 Ubuntu as SSH host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp, ssh-tunnel

I have two virtual servers on the same VCP in Amazon EC2. One is MS Server 2012 and the other is Ubuntu. My work blocks port 3389, so I cannot RDP into the MS Server from work (it is OK from outside work). I can connect to the Ubuntu server via SSH from work. The Ubuntu server's Security Group has an outbound rule, All Ports, All IP addresses open.

I tried to use PuTTY to tunnel RDP through the Ubuntu to the MS server. I used local port 33389. For the destination, I tried both the public IP and the local (VCP) IP address. In all cases, the SSH connects, but the when I start the RDP session it times out after about a minute.

Do I need to do anything else on the Ubuntu server? Is there a command to show the tunnel's properties on the Ubuntu side one once I open the SSH session?